# Composer fails to run (installed with apt)

Tags: 18.04, composer

The composer package from the apt repositories fails with every command (`composer install`, `composer update`, `composer list`, `composer --version`)

Error message

```
PHP Warning:  require(Composer/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/composer on line 8
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Composer/autoload.php' (include_path=':/usr/share/kopano/php') in /usr/bin/composer on line 8
```

(bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/composer/+bug/1768023)

Comment: Note: I have installed composer into my project using instructions from https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: did you resolve this problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: @EmilioGort I no longer use that machine but at the time I installed composer from getcomposer.org and that worked fine

Comment: @chaptuk, Thanks, I made that, remove the composer installed from the apt, and install a new one following the instructions from composer website, like you have in your first comment..